# What is the SubSonic Update Query safe Maximium for In

Tags: sql, subsonic

```
 var query = new Query(Tables.Ticket) {QueryType = QueryType.Update};

                query.WHERE(Ticket.Columns.IsDeleted, false);
                query.AND(Ticket.Columns.IsSold, false);                
                query.AND(Ticket.Columns.SeatId, Comparison.In, seats);
                query.AddUpdateSetting(Ticket.Columns.Price, 123);
                query.Execute();
```

if "seats" is an **List with 2000 items**, is this query poorly written?

Answer (score 1):

My database is MySQL so I can only talk about that, but the performance is still good for such types of queries (depending on what a slow query is in your case. My code can query a table with 160000 record and even use `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(1,2,3,...159999)` in less then 3 seconds). The bottleneck in this case is transporting the large query over the wire, but that is not a big deal in a local lan.

You can even improve the performance with a server side execution (subquery) if you can query the seatids from another table.

```
SubSonic.SqlQuery subQuery = DB
    .Select(Seats.Columns.Id)
    .From<Seats>()
    .Where(Seat.Columns.Type).IsEqualTo(1);

// translates to
// UPDATE tickets SET price = 123
// WHERE seatid IN (SELECT id FROM seats WHERE type = 1)
DB.Update<Tickets>()
  .Set(Tickets.Columns.Price).EqualTo(123)
  .Where(Tickets.Columns.SeatId).In(subQuery)
  .Execute();

// translates to
// UPDATE tickets SET price = 123
// WHERE seatid IN (1,3,5,7,...,2000)
DB.Update<Tickets>()
  .Set(Tickets.Columns.Price).EqualTo(123)
  .Where(Tickets.Columns.SeatId).In(subQuery.ToList<int>())
  .Execute();
```